# Does the incompressibility of a fluid implies that it's also indécompressable?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Incompressible fluids don't exist. But let's consider the hypothetical case that we can find them. Does this incompressibility imply that you can't décompress the fluid either? Or is decompression just negative compression, so that if compression doesn't exist for the fluid (compressibility=0), indécompressibility neither exists (0=0)?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Answer (score 3):

Basically incompressible means that the density of the fluid stays constant. So you can neither compress nor decompress an incompressible fluid.
Its as you correctly said: 'decompression' is just negative 'compression'